# How to create a dynamic html5 table by csv data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, csv

I have csv data like below,

```
No,Name,Year,School,ImageSrc,nnum
1,Gopi,1982,Great High School,/gopi.jpg,11
2,Kanna,1983,Awesome High School,/kanna.jpg,22
3,Raju,1984,Awesome High School,/raju.jpg,33
4,Mani,1985,Awesome High School,/mani.jpg,33
5,Rahul,1986,Awesome High School,/rahul.jpg,33
```

I am using html, jquery with node server and executing the below html code.

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
        <!-- This will be populated dynamically with JavaScript -->
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    // Sample CSV data
    const csvData = `1,Gopi,1982,Great High School,/gopi.jpg,11
    2,Kanna,1983,Awesome High School,/kanna.jpg,22
    3,Raju,1984,Awesome High School,/raju.jpg,33
    4,Mani,1985,Awesome High School,/mani.jpg,33
    5,Rahul,1986,Awesome High School,/rahul.jpg,33, 11
    2,Kanna,1983,Awesome High School,/kanna.jpg,22
    3,Raju,1984,Awesome High School,/raju.jpg,33
    4,Mani,1985,Awesome High School,/mani.jpg,33
    5,Rahul,1986,Awesome High School,/rahul.jpg,33`;


    function createTr(rows) {
        const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        return newRow;
        // rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        //     const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        //     return newRow;
        // })
    }

    function createTd(rowData, newRow){
        //rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
            const newCell = document.createElement("td");
            newCell.textContent = rowData;
            // if(rowIndex % 4 == 0){
            //     newRow = createTr(rows);
            // }
            newRow.appendChild(newCell);
        //});
    }


    // Function to parse CSV data and create dynamic HTML table
    function createTableFromCSV(csv) {
        const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
        const rows = csv.split('\n');
        let newRow = createTr(rows);
        rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
            const rowData = row.split(',');
            if(rowIndex % 4 == 0 && rowIndex != 0) {
                console.log(rowData, rowIndex);
            }
            createTd(rowData, newRow);
        })
        tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
    }

    // Call the function with your CSV data
    createTableFromCSV(csvData);
</script>
```

and getting like,(single row, i need to create 4 columns per row)
[image]

But, I am expecting the dynamic html table should follow the below conditions.

1. Each row(excel data) should create a html table column. Note: not a each cell data.
2. On every 5th row(excel data), html should create a new row and start create the coulmns.

i.e, need the output should similar to the below image,
[image]

Any suggestions.

CSV Data Screen:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the csv data?

Comment: I have added the csv data screen also.

Comment: You split at `\n`, to get single rows. So now the next logical step would be that you split each of those individual rows at the `,` to get the individual cell values ... (That will only work for such "basic" data, btw. As soon as one of the _values_ could also contain a comma, you'll really need a more advanced CSV parser.)

Comment: Do you have any jsbin example? Note: above I have updated code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```js
 // Sample CSV data
    const csvData = `1,Gopi,1982,Great High School,/gopi.jpg,11
    2,Kanna,1983,Awesome High School,/kanna.jpg,22
    3,Raju,1984,Awesome High School,/raju.jpg,33
    4,Mani,1985,Awesome High School,/mani.jpg,33
    5,Rahul,1986,Awesome High School,/rahul.jpg,33, 11
    2,Kanna,1983,Awesome High School,/kanna.jpg,22
    3,Raju,1984,Awesome High School,/raju.jpg,33
    4,Mani,1985,Awesome High School,/mani.jpg,33
    5,Rahul,1986,Awesome High School,/rahul.jpg,33`;


    function createTr() {
        const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        return newRow;
        // rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        //     const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        //     return newRow;
        // })
    }

    function createTd(rowData, newRow){
        //rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
            const newCell = document.createElement("td");
            newCell.textContent = rowData;
            // if(rowIndex % 4 == 0){
            //     newRow = createTr(rows);
            // }
            newRow.appendChild(newCell);
        //});
    }


    // Function to parse CSV data and create dynamic HTML table
    function createTableFromCSV(csv) {
        const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
        const rows = csv.split('\n');
        let newRow = null;
        rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
            const rowData = row.split(',');
            if ((rowIndex % 4) ===0){
                if (newRow !== null){
                        tableBody.appendChild(newRow);              
              }
              newRow=createTr();
            }
            createTd(rowData, newRow);
        })
        tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
    }

    // Call the function with your CSV data
    createTableFromCSV(csvData);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great Work. It is working as expected.